Please help to identity bike model/brand
Please help me to identify what model/brand this is, I have pic searched but can't find anything



A few notes for your own safety and general well-being: 1) Please fix your QR skewer orientation front and rear (especially the front so that the handle isn't pointing forward), 2) add handlebar end plugs so you don't get core sampled in the event of a crash, and 3) consider pointing the front light towards the front.

The frame decals though partly obscured, give the make and model.
Felt Dispatch 9/80
Representative specs from 99spokes or Cyclesolutions


Also, the Motor and Battery and dash-display/speed controls have all been bolted on later.  Same goes for the rear rack which looks quite lightweight and incapable of holding much without wobbling.   The saddle has also been replaced as has the stem.

Nice. Good catch.
